# gulp-sass missing some functionalities

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm starting to work on an ongoing development with gulp and sass.

The workflow was set up for someone not avaialable at the momment and it has been working for people on the team.

Sass compiles on other people machines but not on mine.

I do compile sass on my machine in dozens of other projects without problem but not on this particular one.

I think I did initialize the project correctly but I suspect there is some version or configuration problem involved.

If I `npm install` everything and run `gulp` I get the following error:

```
Error: src/sass/utilities/mixins/_vendor-prefixes.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after "::-webkit-": expected "{", was "&-placeholder"
       "&-placeholder" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
        on line 116 of src/sass/utilities/mixins/_vendor-prefixes.scss
```

I tried commenting the offending lines and running `gulp` again just to stumble with another error:

```
Error: src/sass/base/_base.scss
Error: "ul" failed to @extend "%reset-list".
       The selector "%reset-list" was not found.
       Use "@extend %reset-list !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
        on line 142 of src/sass/base/_base.scss
```

And so on:

```
Error: src/sass/utilities/_placeholders.scss
Error: You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
       You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
       From "@extend %clearfix" on line 38 of src/sass/modules/_calendar.scss
        on line 9 of src/sass/utilities/_placeholders.scss
```

This code works on other machines and all that advanced selector are being used on the development.

If I google for the particular errors I can find errors about them and people suggesting alternate selectors but I suspect that there is something else going on that I should fix.

I have updated my `gulp` to `3.9.1` and `gulp-sass` to `3.1.0` but I get the same errors.

How should I debug this?

Thanks!

> **EDIT**: The errors are clearly stating that the code is not valid but the strange thing is that the same code is working on other peoples machines.

I'll post some code arround some of the errors just for reference anyway:

**_vendor-prefixes.scss:116**

```
// Placeholder focus text
@mixin placeholder-focus($color: $input-color-placeholder) {

  &:focus::-webkit-&-placeholder { color:$color; }
  &:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:$color; } /* FF 4-18 */
  &:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:$color; } /* FF 19+ */
  &:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:$color; } 

}
```

**_base.scss:142**

```
// Unordered and Ordered lists
ul,
ol {
  @extend %reset-list;
}
```

**and the include on _placeholders.scss**

```
// Reset List

%reset-list {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

  li {
    list-style:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your SASS isn't valid. We'd need to see more code to help you (IMO).

Comment: but this same sass is valid on my teammate machine. Anyway I'll edit and post some code arround the errors

Comment: I read that bit, which could mean a version mismatch between packages. You could try installing the exact same version as your colleague's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had nothing to do with functionalities or versions.

As [@rac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4454229/rac) pointed out the code **is** invalid.

The other developer was skiping the errors somehow and the compiled .css did not have the faulty lines or the faulty extends.

Removing all the faulty lines resulted in the same .css and a clean compile.

Thanks!